# Why the Common Language Runtime Cannot Support Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, ironpython

Today the Common Language Run Time Supports Many Languages including Iron Python and Iron Ruby. We can similarly can use J Ruby and J Python in Java Run Time environments . If so why the .net frame work common language run time cannot support for Java? Um just curious to know though u may see this as a dumb question .

Comment: The CLR directly competes with the JVM; why should the CLR support Java-based languages (or vice-versa)?

Comment: BoltClock, there was J#, though ;-)

Comment: Well we can develop Java Applications in .net run time environment

Comment: ya J# it just vanished without a trace

Comment: I think if Java can satisfy the conditions for CLS then it can be run under CLR. Right?

Comment: Perhaps we just need a history lesson? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Java_Virtual_Machine#Sun_vs._Microsoft

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The CLR was actually designed so that it *could* do everything required to run Java. (Indeed, there are some warts in the way IL is defined which are there specifically for compatibility with Java.) You just need a way of converting bytecode to IL, or compiling from Java source code to IL. J# was one way of doing this, but the limitation of using Java 1.1.4 was a pretty huge one.

I suspect the reason for not going further wasn't an issue with running Java as a *language*, but the fact that system libraries would need porting. If you were willing to write Java-like source code but target .NET framework libraries (and *only* .NET framework libraries), with a version of the JLS which switched `java.lang.String` to `System.String` etc, it would be doable. I don't think there'd be much benefit though, when C# is simply a nicer language in almost all ways.

You may be interested in looking at [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) though - an implementation of Java running on the CLI.

Comment: Thank you i will go through the link

Comment: Now you made me curious regarding those warts. I don't have terribly much experience in either JVM bytecode or the CIL, but is there somewhere where those warts are explained?

Comment: @Joey: The annotated CLI specification, if I remember rightly. One example is array covariance (i.e. the ability to convert a reference of type `String[]` to `Object[]` etc.)

Comment: I would agree that if you want CLR, use C#, not just because you might feel the language is nicer, but because there is tools support for using C# with .NET libraries. (And not for Java)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, Java may only be called Java if it compiles to JVM bytecode and runs on a certified JVM (iirc), those were the reasons behind Microsoft's efforts being named J++ and J#.

Then there is still [J#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_Sharp), which is something close to Java, running on the CLR.

Then there is [IKVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKVM) which is an implementation of a JVM and the class library on top of the CLR.

Actually, the class library might be the most annoying thing in this case. J# comes with an own library containing the Java core classes just for that purpose and the language closely ties in with that class library (just as it does in .NET).

The final thing though is probably: Why bother at all? Java itself would be a sub-par language on the CLR, where careful effort is needed to recreate things like its not-actual generics. Due to this interoperability with other CLR languages will likely be limited, too. There are powerful translators from Java to C# if you have a large Java codebase and want to use .NET, but a CLR-native Java, compatible with <s>Su</s>Oracle's would be a lot of effort for something that you'd only want to touch for compatibility purposes and which poorly interfaces with the CLR or other .NET languages.

Comment: Why?  To eat markedshare from Oracle and OpenJDK.  The new release scheme would make an alternative deployment platform much more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

CLR does support J#. In an utopian world CLR should have supported C# and Java, but Java is a competitor to Microsoft's C# and hence it won't support Java.

Comment: okay . that means is there a different in architectures? [CLR and JRE]  if CLR supports JRE then CLR will degrade

Comment: @Kalanamith Of course CLR and JRE are runtime envrionment with different architecture with the sole purpose of having a managed environment. I don't understand what do you mean when you say 'if CLR supports JRE then CLR will degrade '

Comment: If the reason were a competitive one, J# wouldn't have come out to start with, and there wouldn't be warts in the IL design *specifically* put in there to allow Java to run on the CLI. Now it's possible that the engineers wanted it to be available but others in MS didn't, but I think your "hence" is still a bit spurious.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, C# is a superset of Java, so you should technically be able to compile a Java class to CIL.

As others have pointed out, Microsoft has no intention of supporting their competition, however I see there have been some projects, such as [Ja.NET](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/dotnet-developments/janet-a-java-compiler-for-net-clr/), to compile Java code to the CLR. There's also [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/intro.html), which among other things seems to be able to translate Java bytecode to CIL, and includes the Java class library from OpenJDK compiled to .NET.

Comment: 'C# is mostly a superset of Java, so you should technically be able to compile a Java class to IL no problem.' What does this mean?

Comment: I mean that, if C# is a superset of Java, and C# compiles to CLR, then Java should also compile to CLR if someone wrote that compiler -- well, I suppose J# fits that bill, in a way.

Comment: okay i found that CLR is dynamic and JRE is static

Comment: C# and java do share their similarities but essentially are very different, heck, only look at the implementation of generics in both languages.

Comment: I agree. However, since generics in Java don't exist in the compiled code, you can get Java-like generics by simply ignoring the support for generics in the CLR and performing type erasure as in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The respective Virtual Machines act on Intermediate Code in a different language (CIL for .net), and IL for .net and JVM are incompatible with each other.

The IL and Runtime features sometimes disallow a few things, for example Generics in C# are closely tied to how Generics in the .net Runtime work, while Java has a completely different implementation.

Still, there shouldn't be much technically preventing Java from running on .net, just no one did it yet. It's a massive effort, for what? Is there really enough money to make? If there is a business, someone will do it. But if you're in the business of Java, then most likely you are also tied closely to it's tools and environments, e.g. Eclipse and Tomcat, possibly Ant and Maven.