# On IBM i, will java compiler ever "speak" ILE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

On IBM i, will java compiler "speak" ILE? Googling have found various code samples showing how RPG can call java methods, but can't find any reference to java being an ILE language. Are there any plans for this or is there a reason why java cannot be an ILE language on IBM i?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making Java a *full* ILE language, in the same sense that RPG and ILE C are, would be a major undertaking, if it's feasible at all. ILE languages have the property that their compiled modules can be freely mixed and matched when *linking* into an ILE program. In other words, once you compile a module, you conceptually have an ILE module, and it's not very important which language was used in the source code for that module. All you have to do is make sure all the function or procedure prototypes in the calling code are compatible with the corresponding prototypes in the called code.

There was a project that attempted to do exactly this with Java in the Unix/Linux world, called the [GNU Compiler for Java (GCJ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java). The idea was to compile Java modules into a binary form that was directly linkable by (for example) C++ code using GCC. It's unclear whether this ever reached "production quality", and as of this writing, GCJ is no longer part of GCC. So you could look at GCJ as both a proof of concept for a hypothetical ILE Java, and a cautionary tale against ILE Java.

In either case, the effort required to make ILE Java happen is probably not justified by the relatively minor benefit. While you currently can't *link* Java code directly with ILE code, you can still *call* Java from RPG and *call* RPG from Java, which is good enough for most use cases.

What would be easier than a full-blown ILE Java is a native IBM i implementation of the JVM, built *using* ILE languages (the most obvious choices being ILE C or ILE C++), such that PASE is not used at all. But going this route would still require using the existing ways of calling Java from RPG and vice versa, so the benefit would be practically zero. And the effort of porting the JVM to ILE C++ is definitely greater than zero. Also keep in mind that IBM will probably want to update their JVM to more-or-less keep pace with Oracle's JVM, and this will be easier to do with a JVM implemented in PASE rather than a JVM implemented in ILE languages.

Comment: Since ILE is similar in concept to .NET CLR, this answer may prove applicable.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530498/why-the-common-language-runtime-cannot-support-java  Note that ILE came before Java, so unlike CLR, ILE would not include "warts" required for Java compatibility.

Comment: @Charles: It sounds like you're saying ILE is "cleaner" than CLR. I suppose in some sense that might be true. But it's also frankly a mostly lower-level runtime (from a software programmer's point of view) than CLR. I'm no ILE expert, but everything I've personally been exposed to suggests the ILE model is much more like the classic GCC model than either the .NET CLR or Java's JVM. As such, ILE might not have ready machinery to handle the needs of a language like Java or C#. (I.e. I suspect it may suffer the same problems that GCJ did.)

Comment: It was OpenJDK that eventually killed GCJ. It is perfectly possible to pre-compile Java down to native code and remain in full compliance with the spec: https://www.excelsiorjet.com. (Disclaimer: my company makes this.)

Answer (score 2):

Java on IBM i isn't an ILE language ... it actually runs in PASE (for more current releases).

RPG can invoke Java code by creating a JVM and running the java application.

The normal way to invoke RPG code from Java is to use the [ProgramCall](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/ProgramCall.html) or [ProgramCallDocument](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/data/ProgramCallDocument.html) classes.

Comment: If the Java code is always running on the i, then it's easier and more direct to call RPG native methods than to use the ProgramCall or ProgramCallDocument classes. Easier because coding a native method in Java just requires leaving out the method body and adding the "native" keyword. And coding a native method in RPG just requires coding the prototype to be a Java method and then coding the RPG procedure normally.